# Creating views periodically in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm currently using Firebase Analytics to export user-related data to BigQuery.

Is there a way to create a view automatically in BigQuery (every 24 hours for example) as exports from Firebase create a new table everyday, or a single view gathering the data from the tables created daily.
Is it possible to do such things with the WebUI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a view over a wildcard table so that you don't need to update it each day. Here is an example view definition, using the query from one of your previous questions:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS date
FROM `com_test_testapp_ANDROID.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE event_dim.name IN ("EventGamePlayed", "EventGetUserBasicInfos", "EventGetUserCompleteInfos");
```

Let's say that you name this view `com_test_testapp_ANDROID.event_view` (make sure to pick a name that isn't included in the `app_events_*` expansion). Now you can run a query to select yesterday's events, for instance:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event_dim
FROM `com_test_testapp_ANDROID.event_view`
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Or all events in the past seven days:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event_dim
FROM `com_test_testapp_ANDROID.event_view`
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

The important part is having a column in the select list for the view that lets you restrict the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` to whatever range of time you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Elliott Brossard, it's very clear. As the table schema that I'm looking to use is (quite) different from the one used by Firebase, I was wondering if it would be possible to create a new table instead of creating a view to automatically insert data periodically from the tables created daily by Firebase exports. Then it would delete the tables created by Firebase to reduce the amount of data stored.

Comment: Off the top of my head, one thing you could do is to [set up a cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) that runs a query and writes the result to some other table, then deletes the Firebase table that it read from.

Comment: Is this ok in terms of the billing? I mean if I select from the view single day is the condition correctly propagated into the wildcard tables so as the resulting query touches just the single data table?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can confirm by checking the bytes billed estimate for the query in the UI